# How to embed view files in assemblies using Cofoundry

Tags: cofoundry

Is there any Cofoundry specific solution to embedding views in assemblies and use these views by the main website assembly?

For instance I have `/Views/CofoundryPages/Components/BookingRequest/Default.cshtml` which is the view for a ViewComponent that belongs to a separate assembly "Bookings.dll". But I have to leave the cshtml view file in the main website assembly "Website.dll".

Is there a standard way to embed my Default.cshml file in "Bookings.dll" and still have the Cofoundry framework pick it up in its virtual path provider (or what ever it is)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the modular system that Cofoundry itself uses to bootstrap the admin panel and for plugins. There's a couple of things to consider here:

**Register your Assembly**

To register your assembly with Cofoundry, simply add a class that implements `IAssemblyResourceRegistration`. This is a simple marker class that gets picked up by the DI system and registers it with the Cofoundry `AssemblyResourceProvider` so your views can be found. E.g.

```cs
public class ExampleAssemblyResourceRegistration : IAssemblyResourceRegistration
{
}
```

**Ensure your assembly is scanned by Cofoundry**

Your assembly will be automatically scanned by the Cofoundry DI system if it follows the default rules, otherwise you may need to implement an `IAssemblyDiscoveryRule` and register it at startup. More information in the [Cofoundry DI docs](https://www.cofoundry.org/docs/framework/dependency-injection#registering-dependencies-in-other-assemblies)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.